# UIPickerView - Show Images and Text

Tags: uipickerview

Is it possible to show title for row and view for row in the same picker view? What I want to do is allow people to be able to chose a subject room number and colour for a timetable app I am writing. I wanted the colour choice to be an image. It shows the images but not the titles.

```
-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row                
 forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
   if (component == kSubjects) return [PSubjects objectAtIndex:row];
   if (component == kDay) return [PDays objectAtIndex:row];
   //if (component == kLesson) return [PLessonPeriods objectAtIndex:row];
   return [PRoomChoices objectAtIndex:row];

   NSString *title;
   title = [@"" stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d",row];

   return title;
}

-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:  
 (NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
     if (component == kLesson) {
     UIImageView *myIcon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[PLessonPeriods          
     objectAtIndex:row]];
     [myIcon setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 20)];
     return myIcon;}

     else return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I got sneaky and created a UIView and then added a UILabel.

```
-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    // This returns the images
    if (component == kLesson) {
    UIImageView *myIcon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[PLessonPeriods objectAtIndex:row]];
    [myIcon setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 20)];
    return myIcon;}

    // This adds a blank UIIamgeView with a label added as a subview.
    if (component == kSubjects) {
        UIImageView *myIcon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 122, 20)];
        UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 122, 20)];
        myLabel.text = [PSubjects objectAtIndex:row];
        myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [myIcon addSubview:myLabel];
        return myIcon;
    }
    else return 0;

}
```

[image]
If anyone knows of an easier way or can answer my original question that would be supers.